# why child element not hide with parent element jquery.?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I make a collapsible list which is generated by pressing a button "add case".All rows are collapsible.So expand the row select "add case" and press add .it generate a collapsible row inside a row .But I collapse it parent row It should also be hide or collapse,Because it is child of row.I don't know why it is not collapse ?![enter image description here][1]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main problem is in line:

```
$('#' + id).append('<ul><li >' +
```

Next case is added to `li` tag with id `tc_0`, but should be added to element with class `ui-collapsible-content` (element that is collapsible), so the solution will be to change line to:

```
$('#' + id + ' div.ui-collapsible-content').append('<ul><li >' +
```

There is a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/R2DzV/24/).

Comment: I will check let you know

Comment: thanks ..can we give different id.As we give on top like "tc_0","tc_1".can we give inner rows like that "tc_0_0","tc_0_1".

Comment: Updated again. The same link.

Comment: please check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22743611/how-to-add-delete-option-in-row-in-jquery-jquerry-mobile