# How to add delete option in row in jQuery +jQuery Mobile?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

can you please tell me how to add delete option in row.I generated row on button click .I want to add button or icon on row so that user can also delete that row ?
can you please tell me how i will achieve that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modified your Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/R2DzV/28/

Added remove button html:

```
'<a data-role="button" data-mini="true" data-theme="a" class="remove">Remove</a>' +
```

and click handler:

```
.on('click', '.remove', function(){
        $(this).closest('.ui-collapsible').closest('li').remove();
    });
```

Comment: In other word I will explain again after click "add case" button it create a collapsible row .I need button on that , can we do that ..?

Comment: Do you mean to header of row? See [screenshot](http://screencast.com/t/5WUZD7EK).

Comment: exactly sir..I need in that position

Comment: It's not so easy. Look [fiddler](http://jsfiddle.net/R2DzV/35/). Button triggers toggle panel.

Comment: it is not removing ..can you give another remove option of row..as a user friendly

Comment: can we toggle row  on + button , and do nothing row click .then i think button press will work

Comment: Good suggestion, but this whole row is automatically created by JQM framework as a big button with icon. Why [this solution](http://jsfiddle.net/R2DzV/28/) is not acceptable fo you? Looks good and two buttons are same, you can add icons to it.